# Python one line for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I ran into a problem when trying to shorten my script.
First of all this is my script:

```
letters_list =  ['d', '7', '9']
letter_string = ""
for letter in letters_list:
    letter_string +=letter
print letter_string
```

I need to put this whole thing into one line.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply join the characters with [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) like this

```
print "".join(letters_list)
# d79
```

Quoting from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange),

> **CPython implementation detail:** If `s` and `t` are both strings, some Python implementations such as CPython can usually perform an in-place optimization for assignments of the form `s = s + t` or `s += t`. When applicable, this optimization makes quadratic run-time much less likely. This optimization is both version and implementation dependent. For performance sensitive code, **it is preferable to use the `str.join()` method which assures consistent linear concatenation performance** across versions and implementations.

So `str.join` is better than `letter_string += letter` way of joining strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
letter_string = "".join(letters_list)
```